# Oracle error ORA-00600

Tags: oracle, ora-12514, oracle11gr2, ora-00600

I use Oracle 11g. A few days ago I encountered an `ORA-12514` error. I tried to solve it by following [this website suggestions](http://thetendjee.wordpress.com/2007/03/30/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor/):

```
C:\>set oracle_sid=SID
Create a new environment variable called TNS_ADMIN:
in the ‘value’ field, add the new folder: c:\oracle\network\admin

Copy tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora and listener.ora from c:\oracle\product\102\network\admin
Paste into c:\oracle\network\admin

Stop/start listener

C:\>lsnrctl stop
C:\>lsnrctl start
```

after that I receive below error (`ORA-01033`):

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 7 07:33:19 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: pentacms
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Enter user-name:
```

I try to solve the error, but it raised an other error, I try to open log file but I receive below error(last line) 
"ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_nab_less_than_odr], [1](http://thetendjee.wordpress.com/2007/03/30/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor/),
    [46], [32689], [32690], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
    "
please advice me, It's an emergency case.

---

```
FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------------- ------------- -------------- --------------- -------------
TOP_LEVEL_CALL# LOGON_TIM LAST_CALL_ET PDM FAILOVER_TYPE FAILOVER_M FAI
--------------- --------- ------------ --- ------------- ---------- ---
RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP          PDML_STA PDDL_STA PQ_STATU
-------------------------------- -------- -------- --------
CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION
----------------------
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER                                                BLOCKING_SE
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCK FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE
----------------- ---------------- ----------- -----------------------
FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION       SEQ#     EVENT#
---------------------- ---------- ----------
EVENT
----------------------------------------------------------------
P1TEXT                                                                   P1
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P1RAW
----------------
P2TEXT                                                                   P2
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P2RAW
----------------
P3TEXT                                                                   P3
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P3RAW            WAIT_CLASS_ID WAIT_CLASS#
---------------- ------------- -----------
WAIT_CLASS                                                        WAIT_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SECONDS_IN_WAIT STATE               WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO
--------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------------
TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO
--------------------------
SERVICE_NAME                                                     SQL_TRAC SQL_T
---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
SQL_T SQL_TRACE_ SESSION_EDITION_ID CREATOR_ADDR     CREATOR_SERIAL#
----- ---------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------------
ECID
----------------------------------------------------------------
SYS$USERS                                                        DISABLED FALSE

SADDR                   SID    SERIAL#     AUDSID PADDR                 USER#
---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
USERNAME                          COMMAND    OWNERID TADDR
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------------
LOCKWAIT         STATUS   SERVER       SCHEMA# SCHEMANAME
---------------- -------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------
OSUSER                         PROCESS
------------------------------ ------------------------
MACHINE                                                                PORT
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
TERMINAL
----------------
PROGRAM                                                          TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SQL_ADDRESS      SQL_HASH_VALUE SQL_ID        SQL_CHILD_NUMBER SQL_EXEC_
---------------- -------------- ------------- ---------------- ---------
SQL_EXEC_ID PREV_SQL_ADDR    PREV_HASH_VALUE PREV_SQL_ID   PREV_CHILD_NUMBER
----------- ---------------- --------------- ------------- -----------------
PREV_EXEC PREV_EXEC_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------- ------------ --------------------- -------------------------
PLSQL_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------------- -------------------
MODULE                                           MODULE_HASH
------------------------------------------------ -----------
ACTION                           ACTION_HASH
-------------------------------- -----------
CLIENT_INFO
----------------------------------------------------------------
FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------------- ------------- -------------- --------------- -------------
TOP_LEVEL_CALL# LOGON_TIM LAST_CALL_ET PDM FAILOVER_TYPE FAILOVER_M FAI
--------------- --------- ------------ --- ------------- ---------- ---
RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP          PDML_STA PDDL_STA PQ_STATU
-------------------------------- -------- -------- --------
CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION
----------------------
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER                                                BLOCKING_SE
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCK FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE
----------------- ---------------- ----------- -----------------------
FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION       SEQ#     EVENT#
---------------------- ---------- ----------
EVENT
----------------------------------------------------------------
P1TEXT                                                                   P1
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P1RAW
----------------
P2TEXT                                                                   P2
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P2RAW
----------------
P3TEXT                                                                   P3
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P3RAW            WAIT_CLASS_ID WAIT_CLASS#
---------------- ------------- -----------
WAIT_CLASS                                                        WAIT_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SECONDS_IN_WAIT STATE               WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO
--------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------------
TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO
--------------------------
SERVICE_NAME                                                     SQL_TRAC SQL_T
---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
SQL_T SQL_TRACE_ SESSION_EDITION_ID CREATOR_ADDR     CREATOR_SERIAL#
----- ---------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------------
ECID
----------------------------------------------------------------
FALSE FIRST EXEC                  0 000007FF5D4D8D70               2

SADDR                   SID    SERIAL#     AUDSID PADDR                 USER#
---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
USERNAME                          COMMAND    OWNERID TADDR
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------------
LOCKWAIT         STATUS   SERVER       SCHEMA# SCHEMANAME
---------------- -------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------
OSUSER                         PROCESS
------------------------------ ------------------------
MACHINE                                                                PORT
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
TERMINAL
----------------
PROGRAM                                                          TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SQL_ADDRESS      SQL_HASH_VALUE SQL_ID        SQL_CHILD_NUMBER SQL_EXEC_
---------------- -------------- ------------- ---------------- ---------
SQL_EXEC_ID PREV_SQL_ADDR    PREV_HASH_VALUE PREV_SQL_ID   PREV_CHILD_NUMBER
----------- ---------------- --------------- ------------- -----------------
PREV_EXEC PREV_EXEC_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------- ------------ --------------------- -------------------------
PLSQL_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------------- -------------------
MODULE                                           MODULE_HASH
------------------------------------------------ -----------
ACTION                           ACTION_HASH
-------------------------------- -----------
CLIENT_INFO
----------------------------------------------------------------
FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------------- ------------- -------------- --------------- -------------
TOP_LEVEL_CALL# LOGON_TIM LAST_CALL_ET PDM FAILOVER_TYPE FAILOVER_M FAI
--------------- --------- ------------ --- ------------- ---------- ---
RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP          PDML_STA PDDL_STA PQ_STATU
-------------------------------- -------- -------- --------
CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION
----------------------
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER                                                BLOCKING_SE
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCK FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE
----------------- ---------------- ----------- -----------------------
FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION       SEQ#     EVENT#
---------------------- ---------- ----------
EVENT
----------------------------------------------------------------
P1TEXT                                                                   P1
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P1RAW
----------------
P2TEXT                                                                   P2
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P2RAW
----------------
P3TEXT                                                                   P3
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P3RAW            WAIT_CLASS_ID WAIT_CLASS#
---------------- ------------- -----------
WAIT_CLASS                                                        WAIT_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SECONDS_IN_WAIT STATE               WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO
--------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------------
TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO
--------------------------
SERVICE_NAME                                                     SQL_TRAC SQL_T
---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
SQL_T SQL_TRACE_ SESSION_EDITION_ID CREATOR_ADDR     CREATOR_SERIAL#
----- ---------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------------
ECID
----------------------------------------------------------------


SADDR                   SID    SERIAL#     AUDSID PADDR                 USER#
---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
USERNAME                          COMMAND    OWNERID TADDR
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------------
LOCKWAIT         STATUS   SERVER       SCHEMA# SCHEMANAME
---------------- -------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------
OSUSER                         PROCESS
------------------------------ ------------------------
MACHINE                                                                PORT
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
TERMINAL
----------------
PROGRAM                                                          TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SQL_ADDRESS      SQL_HASH_VALUE SQL_ID        SQL_CHILD_NUMBER SQL_EXEC_
---------------- -------------- ------------- ---------------- ---------
SQL_EXEC_ID PREV_SQL_ADDR    PREV_HASH_VALUE PREV_SQL_ID   PREV_CHILD_NUMBER
----------- ---------------- --------------- ------------- -----------------
PREV_EXEC PREV_EXEC_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------- ------------ --------------------- -------------------------
PLSQL_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------------- -------------------
MODULE                                           MODULE_HASH
------------------------------------------------ -----------
ACTION                           ACTION_HASH
-------------------------------- -----------
CLIENT_INFO
----------------------------------------------------------------
FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------------- ------------- -------------- --------------- -------------
TOP_LEVEL_CALL# LOGON_TIM LAST_CALL_ET PDM FAILOVER_TYPE FAILOVER_M FAI
--------------- --------- ------------ --- ------------- ---------- ---
RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP          PDML_STA PDDL_STA PQ_STATU
-------------------------------- -------- -------- --------
CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION
----------------------
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER                                                BLOCKING_SE
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCK FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE
----------------- ---------------- ----------- -----------------------
FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION       SEQ#     EVENT#
---------------------- ---------- ----------
EVENT
----------------------------------------------------------------
P1TEXT                                                                   P1
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P1RAW
----------------
P2TEXT                                                                   P2
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P2RAW
----------------
P3TEXT                                                                   P3
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P3RAW            WAIT_CLASS_ID WAIT_CLASS#
---------------- ------------- -----------
WAIT_CLASS                                                        WAIT_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SECONDS_IN_WAIT STATE               WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO
--------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------------
TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO
--------------------------
SERVICE_NAME                                                     SQL_TRAC SQL_T
---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
SQL_T SQL_TRACE_ SESSION_EDITION_ID CREATOR_ADDR     CREATOR_SERIAL#
----- ---------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------------
ECID
----------------------------------------------------------------


16 rows selected.

SQL> desc dba_user;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object dba_user does not exist


SQL> desc dba_users;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object dba_users does not exist


SQL> desc v$user;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object v$user does not exist


SQL> desc v$users
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object v$users does not exist


SQL> seleect * from dba_users;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "seleect * ..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> select * from dba_users;
select * from dba_users
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only


SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_nab_less_than_odr], [1],
[46], [32689], [32690], [], [], [], [], [], [], []


SQL> alter database mount;
alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01100: database already mounted


SQL> alter database mount;
```

Comment: I already ask this question in http://serverfault.com/ but i dont know how to close that one, it's kind of emergency please help me to solve my problem.if any more information you need please ask me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happenend?
The rdbms tells clearly tells that it is not open for production. Could be crashed. Could be corrupted. Contact your dba to solve.
your database is mounted.

```
alter database open;
```

If it gets open, its ok, if not, check the contents of the alertlog file to see what it is complaining about. If you get a complaint it is most likely wanting to be recovered.
it failed so try:

```
recover database until cancel;
```

and see how far it goes. Your problem could be a damaged online redolog file. If the recovery asks for none existing archivelog files, feed it the members of the redolog groups that contain the changes that the database requests. If you can't get to a complete recovery, restore the database.

```
startup mount    
select member from v$logfile;
-- take a note for their full names.
recover database until cancel;
```

now the recovery process is going to ask for archived log files. If you have them and if they are on the default location, hit enter if the process suggests one. Repeat that until the process fails because the file cannot be found. Then start the recovery again and in stead of accepting a suggested answer, enter the full name of the log members of the log groups. If you are lucky, not all members became corrupt and you can complete the recovery process.

If this does not work, show errors, logs etc. You are very close to having to start all over. That is not the answer that you want to hear but it is pretty realistic ....

Comment: SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_nab_less_than_odr], [1],
[46], [32689], [32690], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Comment: I receive error ORA-00600 that it is internal error, I cannot connect oracle service to find solution, please advice me, I install oracle in my laptop not at office:/

Comment: what happened? 'normally' you get this after a powerfailure on the storage. In that case, the online redolog is damaged. If you have them mulitplexed you could try to recover. see answer edit.

Comment: you right this problem happened because I switch off my computer from main switch several time, in this case what should I do? how I can extract all of my data?and more them to new database & delete previous database?

Comment: I didnt get any back up, so how I restore it? please describe more

Comment: first try the recovery. If that end with recover successfully completed, you  have no more problems, other than a bad habit to switch of you system the way you do (or at least did). You can find the log members using 'select member from v$logfile;' and just try to give them to the recovery process when it asks for a none existing archivelogfile. If you give the wrong one: no problem, give the next one until it stopped complaining or you had them all. In the last case your only chance is to restore a backup.

Comment: If recovery fails, you could try to mess with undo_management=manual and _ALLOW_RESETLOGS_CORRUPTION = TRUE and _CORRUPTED_ROLLBACK_SEGMENTS = (_SYSSMU1$, ....) to try to get the database open in inconsistent state. You have to know what you do .... (be a skilled dba) .... to have a chance.

Comment: I become disappointed, I want to remove I know Oracle from my CV. I cant understand what are u talking about :(( I think I need review my Oracle administrator book again. :(( :(( advice me, I am working with oracle for around 1 year, I just know simple thing as DBA for oracle(for my own computer)

Comment: Rima, I updated the answer. Startup mount; recover database until cancel; and see what happens. Work step for step. Take note of sequence# you are getting and try to make sense out of it.